# msSQL multi delete multi join

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-delete, delete-row, multiple-tables

I would like to delete multiple rows from multiple tables when a condition is true.

I can select the things I want to delete with this:

```
select *
from ProcessStepSt01 
left join ProcessStepSt02 on ProcessStepSt01.Workpiece=ProcessStepSt02.Workpiece
left join ProcessStepSt03 on ProcessStepSt01.Workpiece=ProcessStepSt03.Workpiece
where ProcessStepSt01.Workpiece 
in (
select Workpiece from Workpieces
where datediff(day,workpieces.CreationTime,current_timestamp)>=30
)
```

All ProcessStepStXX contain Workpiece (Primary Key), TeilIO, Start, Ende and TeilVorh. So the result is

```
Workpiece TeilIO TeilVorh Start Ende Workpiece_1 TeilIO_1 ... Workpiece_2 ...
1111      1      1        1     1    (null)      (null)       (null)
abc       1      1        1     1    abc         1            abc
```

But when i replace the **select *** with **delete** i get an error: "wrong syntax next to the left keyword"

I also tried

```
delete ProcessStepSt01,ProcessStepSt02,ProcessStepSt03
```

(everything after the select * remains the same)

but i get " wrong syntax near ',' "

What i want to achive is to delete all rows from ProcessStepSt01, ProcessStepSt02, ProcesStepSt03 where the workpiece matches the selection in the in(...) Statement.

So here are my questions:

1. Why does my syntax not work?
2. How do i make it work?

Finally i want to do it periodically
with

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_AutoRemove 
ON workpieces
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
 ...
END
```

But I think doing it with every insert is a little overkill (approximately one insert every two to three seconds).

Is there a way to do it once every hour/day?

Please note: I am using MSSQL.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete from more than one table at the same time, you need to use three delete statements. However, since in this case all the tables have Workpiece, the statements are easy.

```
DELETE 
FROM ProcessStepSt03
WHERE Workpiece
IN (
SELECT Workpiece FROM Workpieces
WHERE datediff(day,workpieces.CreationTime,current_timestamp)>=30)

DELETE 
FROM ProcessStepSt02
WHERE Workpiece
IN (
SELECT Workpiece FROM Workpieces
WHERE datediff(day,workpieces.CreationTime,current_timestamp)>=30)

DELETE 
FROM ProcessStepSt01
WHERE Workpiece
IN (
SELECT Workpiece FROM Workpieces
WHERE datediff(day,workpieces.CreationTime,current_timestamp)>=30)
```

You can schedule the job to run regularly via SQL Agent.

Of course if one of the ProcessStep tables was the primary, and a record couldn't exist in the others without it (i.e. if there is no ProcessStepSt01 then records cannot exist in ProcessStepSt02 or ProcessStepSt03) then you could set up foreign key relationships from 02 and 03 to 01, with a cascade delete. Then you only need to delete from ProcessStepSt01 and the other records will be deleted automatically.

---

For completeness, if you did want to join tables in a delete statement, you can do it with a syntax like this:

```
DELETE PS1
FROM ProcessStepSt01 PS1
  JOIN Workpieces W ON PS1.Workpiece = W.Workpiece
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, W.CreationTime, current_timestamp) >= 30
```

This will still only allow you to delete from one of the tables in the JOIN, but it is arguably a little nicer than using subqueries, and sometimes you can't achieve what you need to without a join.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, multiple things here.
First: You can't delete from 3 tables simultaneously, you need three separate statements.

```
delete
from ProcessStepSt01 
where Workpiece 
in (
    select Workpiece from Workpieces
    where datediff(day,workpieces.CreationTime,current_timestamp)>=30
)
```

Same for the other tables.

To make it run once a day create a job with SQL Server Agent.
Put your statement in a T-SQL step and schedule it once a day.